# Distribution of noninjective function of random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, data-transformation, joint-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ is a bivariate normal random variable wit mean $(0,0)$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma.$ Suppose that $T:\mathbb R^2\mapsto\mathbb R.$ I wish to compute the distribution of $T(X,Y).$ How could I do it?

I know if $T$ is invertible, so the distribution function of  $T(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
F_T(t)=P(T(X,Y)\le t)=P((X,Y)\le T^{-1}(t))
$$
that can be computed easily. However, it isn't sufficient since $T$ is not necessary invertible, is it? Could anyone give me advice or suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by an invertible $T$? For any fixed real number $t_0$,  the set of all $(x,y)$ that satisfy $T(x,y) = t_0$  are a curve in the $x$-$y$ plane, and the set of all points $(x,y)$ such that $T(x,y) \leq t_0$ is a (measurable) _region_ $A$ in the plane. What you need to find is $$P\{(X,Y) \in A\} = \int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$ which may or may not be easy to compute. For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both have variance $1$, then $P\{X^2+Y^2 \leq a\} = e^{-a/2}$ but if the variances are different, then the integral is messier to compute.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: That's why I was not sure with my method. Thanks by the way for your explanation

Comment: Sorry; that should have read $P\{X^2+Y^2 \leq a\} = 1- e^{-a/2}$. The probability under consideration is an _increasing_ function of $a$.